# Cardinality of the set $S=\{f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R: f \text{ is nowhere continuous}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, continuity

What is the cardinality of the following set?

$$S := \left\{ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R : f \text{ is nowhere continuous} \right\}$$

Clearly, $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, defined as

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x \in \mathbb Q\\
0, \quad x \in \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

belongs to $S$. Let $L := \left\{ (rg) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R : r \in \mathbb R \setminus\{0\} \right\}$. It is clear that $L\sim \mathbb R-\{0\}\sim\mathbb R$. $L$ can be injected into $S$ and hence we conclude that $$\mbox{card} (L) \le \mbox{card}(S)$$ whence card $(S)\ge \mathbb c$, where $\mathbb c$ denotes the cardinality of the continuum.

What more can be said about $\mbox{card} (S)$ (that is, can it be concluded that $\mbox{card} (S) = \mathbb c?)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cardinality is $2^{c}$. Here is a hint: Given any subset $A$ of $\mathbb  R$ define $f(x)=1$ if $x \in A \cap \mathbb Q$, $f(x)=2$ if $x \in A \cap \mathbb Q^{c}$, $f(x)=3$ if $x \in A^{c} \cap \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=4$ if $x \in A^{c} \cap \mathbb Q^{c}$. Check that $f$ is nowhere continuous anf $f_A\neq f_B$ if $A \neq B$.

Comment: Hi sir, I understand that $f$ (suggested in this answer) is nowhere continuous and hence must belong to $S$ but am having difficulty in injecting $S$ in $P(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: There's a one to one correspondence between these $f$'s and the defining subset $A$

Comment: Interestingly, [this question arose recently in a comment in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398387/situations-where-naturally-occurring-mathematical-objects-behave-very-differen/398419#comment1020976_398419).

Comment: @Alan: Thanks. I'm considering $\xi: P(\mathbb R)\to S$ defined by $\xi(A)=f_A$ and for this to be well-defined, we must also define $\xi(\emptyset)$ in which case, I see that $\xi$ is 1-1 thereby proving that $|S|\ge 2^c$. But then what to do with the converse (i.e. $|S|\le 2^c$) ?

Comment: The number of functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is $2^{c}$. @Koro

Comment: sir, I know that $|\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}|=$ cardinality of set of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and your example injects $P(\mathbb R)$ in $S$ but I also want to know how to inject $S$ in $P(\mathbb R)$ to show equality of $|S|$ and $2^c$.

Comment: Sir, I got it. $S\subset \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ so plainly $|S|\le 2^c$ and we are done! Thanks a lot sir.